# Unregister events with new instance of the delegate

Tags: c#, events

```
EventHandler a = new EventHandler(control_RegionChanged);
EventHandler b = new EventHandler(control_RegionChanged);

 if (a == b)
 {
     Console.WriteLine("Same!");
 }
 else
 {
     Console.WriteLine(a.GetHashCode() + " " + b.GetHashCode());
 }
```

This writes `Same!` to the console.

```
control.RegionChanged += new EventHandler(control_RegionChanged);
control.RegionChanged -= new EventHandler(control_RegionChanged);
```

After this code executes, is the `EventHandler` unregistered?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes; delegates are compared on the instance and `MethodInfo`; if those are the same, then it will work. The problem comes when trying to unsubscribe an anonymous method; in that case, you must keep a reference to the delegate in order to unsubscribe.

So:

This is fine:

```
control.SomeEvent += obj.SomeMethod;
//...
control.SomeEvent -= obj.SomeMethod;
```

But this is much riskier:

```
control.SomeEvent += delegate {Trace.WriteLine("Foo");};
//...
control.SomeEvent -= delegate {Trace.WriteLine("Foo");};
```

The correct process with anonymous methods is:

```
EventHandler handler = delegate {Trace.WriteLine("Foo");};
control.SomeEvent += handler;
//...
control.SomeEvent -= handler;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
control.RegionChanged += control_RegionChanged
control.RegionChanged -= control_RegionChanged
```

This should also work (from memory -- haven't really tested it). At least it doesn't create a new eventhandler-reference.

Comment: Actually it does. The compiler does it for you.

Comment: I just tested it, and -- at least in my test -- after adding and removing the handler this way, it works.

Comment: This is simply shorthand, which the compiler still turns into a new EventHandler.

Comment: @Lennaert: Of course it works, I never said it didn't. I said your last sentence is wrong.